# Using command-line gem 'github-pages-health-check' fails on Mac OS X with rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use the github-pages-health-check and unable to get it to work.

OS: OS X 10.8.5
RVM: rvm 1.26.4 (latest)
ruby: 2.1.1

After installation, I try the following...

```
> check
```

and get...

```
-bash: check: command not found
```

I've seen a few other similar threads which blamed path issues, but I'm still not able to connect the final dots here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're simply misunderstanding how to use this gem – where are you getting the impression it comes with a `check` binary?

I found [the gem source on GitHub](https://github.com/github/pages-health-check). The README doesn't mention such a binary. It does mention a local variable by that name, in Ruby code.

Nor is there a `bin` directory in the repository, which is usually where gems put binaries.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm totally trying to wrap my head around ruby and gems still. I got excited when I figured out the concept of command line and gems, I guess I made a poor assumption that this one had a binary. Also, the syntax in the examples with the ">" led me to believe it was a command-line, but otherwise it's not mentioned - that was my oversight.